# Highcharts for R India Map populating same color

Tags: r, highcharts, visualization

I have sample data as shown below:

```
structure(
  list(
    state = c(
      "Kerala",
      "Tamil Nadu",
      "Karnataka",
      "Andhra Pradesh",
      "West Bengal"
    ),
    season = c(
      "Whole Year",
      "Whole Year",
      "Whole Year",
      "Whole Year",
      "Whole Year"
    ),
    production = c(
      129687236641,
      77850542110,
      63458341633,
      25562972210,
      8175996695
    ),
    yield = c(2054454.8,
              5595311.18, 4289195.18, 3434743.57, 5394245.46)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-5L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Made a data out of the original to calculate production (whole year) of each state.

```
highest_production<-crops %>% 
  select(state, season,production, yield)



highest_production<-highest_production %>% 
  group_by(state, season) %>%
  filter(season=="Whole Year") %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm=TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  arrange(desc(production))
```

When I plot map using highchart, the map is having almost same color for most states.

```
hcmap("countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed",
      data=highest_production,
      value="production",
      joinBy = c("name", "state"),
      bordercolor="lightgrey",
      borderwidth=0.3) %>% 
  hc_title(text="State-wise Production For Whole Year") %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops=color_stops())
```

I tried playing with hc_colorAxis (mincolor and maxcolor, or using list from and to etc) yet it is populating same color for most states (image below). What could be the problem?
[image: rplot india map]

Comment: That is probably because most values are lower than some values (outliers)? So you could change your scale. Could you please share your complete data?

Comment: Here is the link to the dataset. Note that I have summed up the production value for the entire year of all states (group_by=state) for all years in the above map: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nikhilmahajan29/crop-production-statistics-india

Comment: I don't see any problems from the Highcharts side. It seems like you have more data in the lower range and you can consider adding more colorAxis stops. Example: before: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ogc3we5/ , after:  https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dsh9yLct/